# Steam Scrapy Problems

Tags: python, scrapy, steam

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class GameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'game'
    allowed_domains = ['store.steampowered.com']
    start_urls = ['https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_230_7&category1=998&infinite=1']

    def parse(self, response):

        print(response.body)
        game_href = str(response.xpath(".//@href").extract())
        
        print(game_href)
```

My problem is when I run the `scrapy`, I only get 17 links (50 links total). I try to check `response.body`, and it's right.

Answer (score 1):

The page returns json data, yet you are parsing it as html.

If you only parse the actual html part, you will get all of the links:

```
>>> fetch('https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_230_7&category1=998&infinite=1')
2020-11-04 07:13:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://store.steampowered.com/search/results/?query&start=0&count=50&dynamic_data=&sort_by=_ASC&snr=1_7_7_230_7&category1=998&infinite=1> (referer: None)
>>> data = response.json()
>>> sel = scrapy.Selector(text=data['results_html'])
>>> game_href = sel.xpath('//@href').getall()
>>> len(game_href)
50
```